# Cookies not getting Deleted for Instagram Integration

Tags: iphone, xcode, cookies, instagram

I have integrated Instagram in my App, I am able to Login, and Logout but when i am trying to re-Login than its not asking for the credentials again. its getting logged in with the same old credentials, but when i am deleting the the cookies and history from Safari/Settings from iPhone or Simulator than only its working else not working

The Login Process that i am using is

```
 // here i can store accessToken
    IGAppDelegate* appDelegate = (IGAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:appDelegate.instagram.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
IGListViewController* viewController = [[IGListViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

for Logout i am trying like this way :
static NSString* kDialogBaseURL = @"https://instagram.com/";

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray* instagramCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kDialogBaseURL]];
    NSLog(@"Cookies %@",cookies);
    NSLog(@"Cookies %@",instagramCookies);
    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in instagramCookies)
    {
        NSLog(@"cookies is %@",cookie);
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
        NSLog(@"Cookies %@",cookies);
```

Comment: Are you solved this problem???

Comment: Nope...i am struck and left that presenlty

Answer (score 0):

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [cookies cookies]) {
    if ([cookie.domain.uppercaseString containsString:@"instagram.com".uppercaseString]) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```